# Cordova file transfer plugin: uploading files to server in windows phone 8(WP8)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am working on Cordova 3.3 windows phone 8 project.
I have installed File transfer plugin and trying to upload jpeg files to server.
Mimetype:multipart/form-data
Trustallhosts parameter is set to true.

On checking the file transfer plugin implementation
I dont see how the request stream that we are trying to upload is getting assigned to the httpwebrequest object.

Is anybody able to upload files using the file transfer plugin in cordova wp8 app?
If yes,please advise

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: this thread can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910891/cordova-file-is-undefined-for-windows-wp8